# Rust returning a vector of pathbufs from a function after using fs::read_dir

Tags: rust, file-io, iterator, unwrap

Hi i found some code on here that seems to work to return a Vec from a function but im having trouble understanding the code. The code is below, i have added comments to show where im getting confused.

```
fn read_filename_from_dir<P>(path: P) -> Result<Vec<PathBuf>, io::Error> where P: AsRef<Path>,{
   fs::read_dir(path)? //returns result<readDir> ? unwraps to readDir
   .into_iter() //creates a new iter containing result<DirEntry> 
   .map(|x| x.map(|entry| entry.path()))
   .collect()  //the double map confuses me. this is where i lose understanding
}
```

I would assume since we have an iter containing Result's wouldnt we have to first unwrap each DirEntry then just map once unwrapped or does the double map unwrap somehow?
how would you unwrap an iter of results? using  map(|x| x.unwrap()) ?

Answer (score 2):

The first map unpacks the `io::Result<DirEntry>`.
read_dir is a lazy iterator, so it won't return an error immediately, but only after you try to read the dir by starting iterating. It could also return Ok for the first few entries, and then return an Err.

The internal map transforms DirEntry to PathBuf.

Here's how you could rewrite it with types:

```
   .map(|entry_result: io::Result<DirEntry>| -> io::Result<PathBuf> {
       entry_result.map(|entry: DirEntry| -> PathBuf {
           entry.path()
       })
   })
```

collect() is pretty magical too, because not only it builds a Vec, but also short circuits on the first Err, and instead of returning `Vec<io::Result<PathBuf>>` it actually returns `io::Result<Vec<PathBuf>>`. This behaviour is specific for iterators with Result's. There's an [example of this behaviour in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect).

You could rewrite the same piece in imperative mode:

```
    let mut paths = Vec::<PathBuf>::new();
    for entry_result in fs::read_dir(path)? {
        let entry = entry_result?;
        paths.push(entry.path());
    }
    Ok(paths)
```

It is not longer, but much more straightforward and readable for a wider audience.